# Fitted or equipped?

Tags: verbs, translation

On [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/21245/what-is-the-belly-pod-on-this-beech-a200-super-king-air/21253#21253), I used this sentence:

> There are two C-12 aircraft fitted with CEASAR.

Is `fitted` the correct word to use?

What I want to say in French:

> Il y a deux appareils C-12 équipés avec/de CEASAR.

My bilingual dictionary suggests `equipped` instead, and `fitted with` seems [related to harmony](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fit+with), like for clothes.

[image]

Still, `fitted` seems more familiar to me, from my technical readings. Am I wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fitted implies the aircraft was created with CEASAR in mind, so that everything fits into place perfectly.

Equipped is similar, but implies you can 'equip' CEASAR into the aircraft at any point after construction.

Since I have no idea what CAESAR or a C-12 is, I'll use a more known example:

> The bedroom is equipped with a 12-inch TV.
>
> The kitchen is fitted with a gas stove.

An interesting note is that a person who works with mechnical parts like this is called a Fitter and Turner:

> A fitter and turner refers to a person who manufactures mechanical parts (turner) and assembles (fitter) those parts together to manufacture a mechanical device.

Comment: Thanks, very clear. I should have used `equipped with` since the equipment was not part of the initial design.